# Colapsar una tabla acorde a un criterio

Tags: r

Para una columna llamada:

```
  Report_Crop_SFC:
          Pos      Library     Ref    AD_REF     ALT     AD_ALT    Coverage
          135       PV002      A         2        C        3           5
          461       PV002      G         0        A        14          14
          461       PV003      G         0        A        7           7
          461       PV011      G         0        A        12          12
          461       PV014      G         0        A        1           1
          461       PV061      G         0        A        47          49
          881       PV002      G         0        A        5           5
```

Quiero colapsarla de tal manera que si aparece el mismo cambio en el mismo sitio se cotraiga de esta manera, sumandose los valores de AD_REF y AD_ALT:

```
Pos      Library                       Ref    AD_REF     ALT     AD_ALT    Coverage
135       PV002                           A         2        C        3           5
461       PV002/PV003/PV011/PV014/PV061   G         0        A        81          83
881       PV002                           G         0        A        5           5
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes algunos problemas en como planteas el agrupamiento:

1. Por el ejemplo que muestras, el agrupamiento no parece ser por `Library` sino por `Pos`
2. Tal como lo has planteado, estarías aplicando la función `sum` sobre columnas que noson numéricas (son factores), de ahí el error.

Entiendo que la forma de resolverlo sería así:

```
Report_Crop_SFC <- read.table(text="Pos      Library     Ref    AD_REF     ALT     AD_ALT    Coverage
135       PV002      A         2        C        3           5
461       PV002      G         0        A        14          14
461       PV003      G         0        A        7           7
461       PV011      G         0        A        12          12
461       PV014      G         0        A        1           1
461       PV061      G         0        A        47          49
881       PV002      G         0        A        5           5", header=TRUE)


aggregate(cbind(AD_REF,AD_ALT,Coverage) ~ Pos, Report_Crop_SFC, sum)

  Pos AD_REF AD_ALT Coverage
1 135      2      3        5
2 461      0     81       83
3 881      0      5        5
```

Usamos una forma de invocar `aggregate()` que es muy compacta, básicamente `aggregate(<formula de agregación>, <data.frame>, <función a aplicar>)` la formula de agregación tiene el siguiente formato: `<columnas a agregar> ~ <columnas a agrupar>`

Ahora bien, para el resto de la columnas, obviamente no sirve usar el `sum` y por tu ejemplo además, buscas concatenar los valores de `Library`, con lo cual necesitarías aplicar distintas funciones de agregación según las columnas. Cosa que con `agreggate` es complicado, por que deberías realizar tres agrupaciones para aplicar cada función y luego juntar los resultados con `merge()`.

```
merge (
  merge(
    aggregate(Library ~ Pos, Report_Crop_SFC, paste0, collapse="/"),
    aggregate(cbind(AD_REF,AD_ALT,Coverage) ~ Pos, Report_Crop_SFC, sum)
  ),
  aggregate(cbind(Ref,ALT) ~ Pos, Report_Crop_SFC, head, 1)
)
```

Vemos que posible pero, mucho más fácil es pasarte a `tidyverse` y resolverlo de forma más clara y simple:

```
library(tidyverse)

Report_Crop_SFC %>% 
  group_by(Pos) %>% 
  summarise(Library = paste0(Library, collapse='/'),
            Ref = first(Ref),
            AD_REF = sum(AD_REF),
            ALT = first(ALT),
            AD_ALT = sum(AD_ALT),
            Coverage = sum(Coverage)
            )


# A tibble: 3 x 7
    Pos Library                       Ref   AD_REF ALT   AD_ALT Coverage
  <int> <chr>                         <fct>  <int> <fct>  <int>    <int>
1   135 PV002                         A          2 C          3        5
2   461 PV002/PV003/PV011/PV014/PV061 G          0 A         81       83
3   881 PV002                         G          0 A          5        5
```

Comment: he planteado mal la pregunta, acabo de editarla para que en la opción de librería se peguen aquellas librerías que aparecen con ese cambio

Comment: En realidad tampoco es demasiado complejo con `aggregate`, te dejo los dos ejemplos.